# How to predicate all pairs in a given list in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, combinations

When given a list I would like to compute all the possible combinations of pairs in the list.

e.g 2) input is a list (a,b,c) I would like to obtain pairs (a,b) (a,c) (b,c)

e.g 1) input is a list (a,b,c,d) I would like to obtain pairs (a,b) (a,c) (a,d) (b,c) (b,d) and (c,d)

Comment: `pairs (x:xs) = [ (x,y) | y<-xs ] ++ pairs xs ; pairs [] = []`, in Haskell notation. The easiest is to translate this into a Prolog predicate that will produce all these pairs one by one on backtracking, as the answer by Mog suggests you do. `y<-xs` corresponds to `member(Y,XS)` ; `++` corresponds to a disjunction.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Using `select/3` twice (or `select/3` once and `member/2` once) will allow you to achieve what you want here. I'll let you work out the details and ask for help if it's still troublesome.</strike>

BTW, Prolog syntax for list isn't `(a, b, c)` but `[a, b, c]` (well, it's syntactic sugar but I'll leave it at that).

**edit**: as @WillNess pointed out, you're not looking for any pair `(X, Y)` but only for pairs where `X` is before `Y` in the list.

DCGs are a really good fit: as @false described, they can produce a [graphically appealing solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462039/prolog-list-homework/8466102#8466102):

```
... --> [] | [_], ... .

pair(L, X-Y) :-
    phrase((..., [X], ..., [Y], ...), L).
```

Alternatively, if you use SWI-Prolog, a call to `append/2` does the trick too, in a similar manner, but is less efficient than DCGs:

```
pair2(L, X-Y) :-
    append([_, [X], _, [Y], _], L).
```

You can do it with a basic recursion, as @WillNess suggested in his comment. I'll leave this part for him to detail if needed!

Comment: perhaps not select/3, but simple recursion over the input list, as we apparently don't need the elements preceding the one that is picked first (judging from the description, which omits `(b,a)`, `(c,b)` pairs etc).

Comment: yup, I didn't check the expected output carefully enough, you should post your comment as an anwer!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so to translate the Haskell definition

```
pairs (x:xs) = [ (x,y) | y <- xs ]
                ++ pairs xs 
pairs []     = []
```

*(which means, pairs in the list with head `x` and tail `xs` are all the pairs `(x,y)` where `y` is in `xs`, and also the pairs in `xs`; and there's no pairs in an empty list)*

as a *backtracking* Prolog predicate, producing the pairs one by one on each *redo*, it's a straightforward one-to-one re-write of the above,

```
pair( [X|XS], X-Y) :- member( ... , XS)    % fill in 
                      ; pair( XS, ... ).   %    the blanks 
%% pair( [], _) :- false.
```

To get *all* the possible pairs, use `findall`:

```
pairs( L, PS) :- findall( P, pair( L, P), PS).
```

Consider using `bagof` if your lists can contain logical variables in them. Controlling `bagof`'s backtracking could be an intricate issue though.

`pairs` can also be written as a (nearly) deterministic, non-backtracking, recursive definition, constructing its output list through an accumulator parameter as a functional programming language would do -- here in the top-down manner, which is what Prolog so excels in:

```
pairs( [X|T], PS) :- T = [_|_], pairs( X, T, T, PS, []). 
pairs( [_], []).
pairs( [], []).

pairs( _, [], [], Z, Z).
pairs( _, [], [X|T], PS, Z) :- pairs( X, T, T, PS, Z).
pairs( X, [Y|T], R, [X-Y|PS], Z) :- pairs( X, T, R, PS, Z).
```

Comment: +1: Some comments: There is a fundamental difference to Haskell here: And that are the variables. Because of this, `findall/3` does not work with lists containing variables. Consider `bagof/3`. For your last version: you do not need that red cut in disguise `(->)/2`. You can do it in all purity with `T=[_|_]` ...`; T = []`. Also instead of `(:)/2` use `(-)/2` which is the idiomatic pair constructor in Prolog.

Comment: @false thanks, changed that. Although here it was a green cut, I thought. About functor name, I've used ':' for pairs too, and '-' for me is idiomatic indicator of a difference list. :)

Comment: @false no, not a green cut at all. *red* cut it was.

Comment: Look at:  `?- catch(keysort([a],L),error(E,_),true).` the answer is `type_error(pair,a).` So, `a-b` is a `pair`. This is standard terminology. Difference lists are usually written as two arguments. Both `(-)/2` and `(\)/2` for differences often lead to extra errors.

Comment: @false ah, I see, '-' happens to be used as default pair functor *w.r.t. `keysort/2`*, in several Prolog implementations, is what you mean. Of course *in general* pair is anything that pairs up any two things, and can have any functor at all, '-', '/', `not_a_pair`, etc. :)

Comment: "several Prolog implementations" and in the standard. Several means SWI, B, GNU, SICStus, XSB ... almost all having `keysort/2`. The first time `(-)/2` was explicitly called a pair is probably 1983 or so. Compare it to Haskell: Also there, any constructor with two independent types might be a pair, but still the notion is reseved to (a,b).

Comment: @false thanks a lot for the explanation! I don't remember from which book exactly did I get that impression... (btw in Haskell there *is* an abstract [notion of a `Pair`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lifting)).

Comment: the sources: Haskell report: [zip takes two lists and returns a list of corresponding **pairs**](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html#$vzip). Mycroft&O'Keefe Prolog type checker dated 1983-06-23: [`:- type pair(X,Y) --> X-Y. %  for keysort`](http://www.j-paine.org/prolog/tools/files/prolog.typ)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible way of solving this.

The following predicate `combine/3` is true
if the third argument corresponds to a list
contains pairs, where the first element of each pair
is equal to the first argument of `combine/3`.
The second element of each pair will correspond to an item
of the list in the second argument of the predicate `combine/3`.
Some examples how `combine/3` should work:

```
?- combine(a,[b],X).
X = [pair(a,b)]

?- combine(a,[b,c,d],X).
X = [pair(a,b), pair(a,c), pair(a,d)]
```

Possible way of defining `combine/3`:

```
combine(A,[B],[pair(A,B)]) :- !.

combine(A,[B|T],C) :-
  combine(A,T,C2),          % Create pairs for remaining elements in T.
  append([pair(A,B)],C2,C). % Append current pair and remaining pairs C2.
                            % The result of append is C.
```

Now `combine/3` can be used to define `pair/2`:

```
pairs([],[]).      % Empty list will correspond to empty list of pairs.
pairs([H|T],P) :-  % In case there is at least one element.
  nonvar([H|T]),   % In this case it expected that [H|T] is instantiated.
  pairs(H,T,P).

pairs(A,[B],[pair(A,B)]) % If remaining list contains exactly one element,
  :- !.                  % then there will be only one pair(A,B).
pairs(A,[B|T],P) :-      % In case there are at least two elements.
  combine(A,[B|T],P2),   % For each element in [B|T] compute pairs
                         % where first element of each pair will be A.
  pairs(B,T,P3),         % Compute all pairs without A recursively.
  append(P2,P3,P).       % Append results P2 and P3 together.
```

Sample usage:

```
?- pairs([a,b,c],X).
X = [pair(a, b), pair(a, c), pair(b, c)].

?- pairs([a,b,c,d],X).
X = [pair(a, b), pair(a, c), pair(a, d), pair(b, c), pair(b, d), pair(c, d)].
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `append/` to iterate through the list:

```
?- append(_,[X|R],[a,b,c,d]).
X = a,
R = [b, c, d] ;
X = b,
R = [c, d] ;
X = c,
R = [d] ;
X = d,
R = [] ;
false.
```

Next, use `member/2` to form a pair `X-Y`, for each `Y` in `R`:

```
?- append(_,[X|R],[a,b,c,d]), member(Y,R), Pair=(X-Y).
X = a,
R = [b, c, d],
Y = b,
Pair = a-b ;
X = a,
R = [b, c, d],
Y = c,
Pair = a-c ;
X = a,
R = [b, c, d],
Y = d,
Pair = a-d ;
X = b,
R = [c, d],
Y = c,
Pair = b-c ;
X = b,
R = [c, d],
Y = d,
Pair = b-d ;
X = c,
R = [d],
Y = d,
Pair = c-d ;
false.
```

Then, use `findall/3` to collect all pairs in a list:

```
?- findall(X-Y, (append(_,[X|R],[a,b,c,d]), member(Y,R)), Pairs).
Pairs = [a-b, a-c, a-d, b-c, b-d, c-d].
```

Thus, your final solution can be expressed as:

```
pairs(List, Pairs) :-
    findall(X-Y, (append(_,[X|R],List), member(Y,R)), Pairs).
```

An example of use is:

```
?- pairs([a,b,c,d], Pairs).
Pairs = [a-b, a-c, a-d, b-c, b-d, c-d].
```